# simplify an expression to include only union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

simplify:$$
(A\cup B)\cap (B\cup C\cup D)\cap(B\cup C\cup D')
$$ 
the end result should only have one $\cup$ and one $\cap$ symbol.

a bit confused on how to start. I think we can use the distributive property here. Take $x=A\cup B$ and the other terms as $y$ and $z$, respectively.

however, i'm not sure which distributive property since the equation has 2 intersect symbols and the properties have union and intersect symbol (I hope that made sense).

Comment: that's a $D' \neq D$ ?

Comment: yes, D' is the complement of D.

Comment: Are you restricted as to which method to use? There are identities, Venn diagrams, inclusion tables, etc.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, we have to use laws of logic

Comment: Could you clarify? Which laws? Set identities, as I used in my answer, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can use the distributive law of union over intersection:
$$
\begin{align}
(A \color{red}{\cup B})\cap (\color{red}{B \cup} C\cup D)\cap(\color{red}{B \cup} C\cup D') &=
\color{red}{B \cup} \left(A \cap (\color{green}{C \cup} D) \cap (\color{green}{C \cup} D')\right) \\
&= B \cup \left( A \cap \left(\color{green}{C \cup} (D \cap D') \right) \right) \\
&= B \cup (A \cap C)
\end{align}
$$
Note that the last equality is because $D \cap D' = \varnothing$ for any set $D$.

Comment: No problem. Instead of leaving "thank you" comments, though, it is good practice to upvote (up arrow on the left) any (correct) answer that you find helpful. You should also accept ("V" like symbol below the arrows) the answer the answer that you find most satisfying, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using identities.

$$(A\cup B)\cap (B\cup C\cup D)\cap(B\cup C\cup D')$$
$$=(A\cup B)\ \cap\ [(B\cup C)\cup(D\cap D')]$$
$$=(A\cup B)\ \cap\ [(B\cup C)\cup \emptyset]$$
$$=(A\cup B)\ \cap\ (B\cup C)$$
$$=(B\cup A)\ \cap\ (B\cup C)$$
$$=B\ \cup\ (A\cap C)$$

Comment: awesome, thank you. what property did you use in the first line? distributive? if you could please explain that part, it would be great =)

Comment: @Justin: Yes, the distributive property of union over intersection. I treated $B\cup C$ as one set [call it $P$], and used $(P\cup D)\cap(P\cup D')=P\cup(D\cap D')$.

Comment: makes sense now. thanks